# My code shows this error whatever I try, and when I click on the link it shows there's a 404

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

Whatever I seem to try (using different secret keys, trying to fix small errors) this error shows when I run my code.

I have tried making small changes to the code such as changing the secret key, fixing indentation, etc. However, I do not understand why my code does not work, so I wanted to ask here.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, join_room

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secretcodehere29403949493'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route("/template/chat.html/")
def chat():
  return render_template("template/login.html")


@app.route(r'/template/login.html/')
def login():
  return render_template('login.html')


@socketio.on('message', namespace='/chat')
def chat_message(message):
  print("message = ", message)
  emit('message', {'data': message['data']}, broadcast=True)


@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/chat')
def test_connect():
  emit('my response', {'data': 'Connected', 'count': 0})

if __name__ == '__main__':
  socketio.run(app)
```

- Restarting with stat
- Debugger is active!
- Debugger PIN: 183-355-780
  (18512) wsgi starting up on http://127.0.0.1:5000

nothing displays in the link it provides in the error here, and localhost:8080 shows nothing.

Comment: try http://127.0.0.1:5000 ?

Comment: just tried that, the same result. Also, even if I did get the link did work, I think it only takes me to the debugger and the code still doesn't work somehow. Should I post the HTML?

Comment: the path is /template/login.html/ and if something went gone, the debugger will show u the error info. dive into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes may not be correct. When you call `app.route`, you're mapping a url to the function.

In your case the urls in your routes are defining: `127.0.0.1:5000/template/chat.html/` and `127.0.0.1:5000/template/login.html/`.

Try changing a route to `@app.route('/')` and then navigating to `127.0.0.1:5000` or `localhost:5000`

Comment: thanks! that seemed to make the traceback show in there. However, my code still shows a ```jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: template/login.html```. Does anyone know how I might fix this? (though this is mostly unrelated). Thanks again for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Concerning [your last comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56764352/my-code-shows-this-error-whatever-i-try-and-when-i-click-on-the-link-it-shows-t/56787649#comment100098101_56764962) (I can't comment on dylanj.nz's post), the [`render_template`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#rendering-templates) function uses the default `templates` folder, so there is no need to specify it on your code :)

Thus you should remove `template/` in this line: 
  `return render_template("template/login.html")`.

If you want to change the default folder location, add a `template_folder` instruction in your `app = Flask(...)`.
Example:

```py
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='application/templates', static_folder='heyanotherdirectory/static')
```